# Jquery left right navigation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have the following simple html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {  // left
       $('#prev').click();   
       return false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {  // right
       $('#next').click();
       return false;
    }
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a id="next" href="/next">next</a>
<a id="prev" href="/prev">prev</a>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to make users navigate articles using right and left keyboard keys. So clicking the left arrow should go to the /prev link and clicking the right arrow should go to the /next link. It's not working in any browser for some reason I can't get.

Thanks

Comment: wrap in document ready?

Comment: tried wrapping doc ready but no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){    
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {  // left
       window.location.href = $('#prev').attr('href');   
       return false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {  // right
       window.location.href =  $('#next').attr('href');  
       return false;
    }
});
```

You're calling `.click()` on an element, but that doesn't trigger a `click` event, that's that `.trigger()` is for:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {  // left
       $('#prev').trigger('click');   
       return false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {  // right
       $('#next').trigger('click');
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: He's not binding the handler by what he's doing, he's calling the function that is bound, which doesn't exist. Looks like he needs a document ready wrapper too.

Comment: the first function works well but the second doesn't work even after adding document ready